# Deploying a Website and a MVC4 web application as a single IIS site with a virtual app inside with msbuild/msdeploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, msbuild, webdeploy

I have 2 web projects in my solution:

- Our marketing/public site, which is a small website build with **ASP.NET WebPages 2**.
- Our admin application which is a **MVC4** application.

They are currently deployed in IIS 7.0 as

/**wwwmywebsitecom** (root for the public website)
---/**admin** (root for the MVC4 app)
---/Content
---/Scripts
..etc

The reasons to separate the public site from the admin part is to make sure the first load FAST and doesn't wait for the heavy setup mechanism that is triggered by the mvc4 app (bundles & minification, webapi routes, index creation, initial setup, etc).

My goal is to package these apps and deploy it to our test server by using MsBuild and MsDeploy. Right now I'm doing this by hand but for obvious reasons I need to automate the process. (Planning on including a CI server after I have this part figured out).

I have read several posts but none of them address this type of nested scenario.

Is it possible?
Any help would be more than appreciated.

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `admin` folder on the remote server is marked as an "application", you should just be able to deploy both sites one after another.

Comment: Yes, it is marked as an application. I was hoping to deploy it all at once but honestly I put this on hold. I will give this a try and come back to let you know if this works. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that, as you suggested, there is nothing preventing me from deploying first the website, then the mvc4 application as a virtual application inside the website. However, I'm looking for a way to create a **single** package, so everything can be deployed at once.